# mcc function can't return value,why?

Tags: matlab, exe, mcc

I use matlab mcc to create a standalone application exe file, then I use php to call the exe file. but I can't get the function return value,it's always empty!! here is my test example in  m file

```
function result=mysum(in)
if nargin<1
    in=[1,2,3];
else
    in=str2num(in); 
end
result=sum(in);
end
```

then I use the command `mcc -m mysum.m` to create exe file(I have already configured the matlab compiler).

here is the php file

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php  
    exec('F:\myevm\apache\htdocs\shs.exe [2,2,3,3,3] [4,4,4,4,4] 356 1567 1678',$ars);
    echo '<br>';
    echo $ars[0];

    ?>

    </body>
   </script>
   </html>
```

however ,the `$ars[0]` is always empty!!
I tried to find answer by myself or through the Internet,but failed .  give me a help, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note two things:

1. You have your function set up to accept a single input argument.
2. When you run an application from the Windows command line, arguments are passed in as strings.

So if you type `mysum 1` (either in MATLAB on the uncompiled program, and I would guess also if you do this from the Windows command line on the compiled program, although I haven't tested this) it will work, giving the answer `1`, and if you type `mysum [1,2]` it will work, giving the answer `3`. Note that `mysum [1,2]` is **different** from `mysum([1,2])`, as it is being passed the **string** `'[1,2]'`, not the array of doubles `[1,2]`.

But if you type `mysum 1 2` it will fail, as you are now passing two string input arguments in, and your function is set up to only accept one.

Rewrite your function so that it accepts a variable number of input arguments (take a look at `varargin` to achieve that), applies `str2num` in turn to each of the inputs (which will be `varargin{1}` to `varargin{n}` if you've used `varargin`), and then sums them individually.